# Randomly generate shape and colour and draw to canvas

Tags: java, android, drawing

The generatePoints method is supposed to create 'num' number of random shapes (limited to square, triangle, circle) with random colour (limited to red, green, blue). So far all the program does is draw one or two objects, never two of the same shape, always the same colour, and never a triangle. I've been banging my head against a wall for the past while, hopefully someone will be able to point out my blunder(s)!

Thanks in advance! Any suggestions would be appreciated

scatterPlotActivity.java:

```
package scatter.plot;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class ScatterPlotActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        scatterPoint[] points = generatePoints();
        for(int i = 0; i<points.length; i++)
            drawPoint(points[i]);

    }

    public void drawPoint(scatterPoint point) {
        FrameLayout main = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
        main.addView(point);
    }


    public scatterPoint[] generatePoints(){
        Point point = new Point(0,0);
        int shape=0;
        int c=0;
        Paint colour = new Paint(Color.RED);

        int num = 20; //number of points to generate, maybe when I grow a brain I'll know how to prompt the user for this

        scatterPoint[] points = new scatterPoint[num];

        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            point.x = (int) (Math.random()*screenMetrics().x);
            point.y = (int) (Math.random()*screenMetrics().y);

            shape = (int) Math.round((Math.random()*2));

            c = (int) Math.round((Math.random()*2));
            switch(c){
                case 0:
                    colour.setColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    colour.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    colour.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println("Point "+i+": ("+point.x+", "+point.y+") "+shape+" "+colour);
            points[i] = new scatterPoint(this, point, shape, colour);
        }

        return points;
    }

    public Point screenMetrics(){
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        return size;
    }
}
```

scatterPlot.java:

```
package scatter.plot;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.view.View;

public class scatterPoint extends View { //scatterPlot point has a position, shape, and colour
    private final Point coordinates;
    private final int itemShape;
    private Paint itemColour = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    public scatterPoint(Context context, Point p, int shape, Paint colour) { // Constructor
        super(context);
        coordinates = p;
        itemShape = shape;
        itemColour = colour;
    }

     @Override
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         super.onDraw(canvas);

         int radius = 5; //hardcoded item size

         switch(itemShape){
            case 0:
                canvas.drawRect(coordinates.x - radius, coordinates.y - radius, coordinates.x + radius, coordinates.y + radius, itemColour);
                break;
            case 1:
                Path path = new Path();
                path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
                path.moveTo(coordinates.x - radius, coordinates.y - radius);
                path.lineTo(coordinates.x, coordinates.y + radius);
                path.lineTo(coordinates.x + radius, coordinates.y - radius);
                path.lineTo(coordinates.x - radius, coordinates.y - radius);
                path.close();

                Paint fill = itemColour;
                fill.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

                canvas.drawPath(path, fill);
                break;
            case 2:
                canvas.drawCircle(coordinates.x, coordinates.x, radius, itemColour);
                break;

         }
     }

    public Point getCoordinates(){
        return coordinates;
    }

    public int getShape(){
        return itemShape;
    }

    public Paint getColour(){
        return itemColour;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the Android libraries include [java.util package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html)?
If yes, you could use the `java.util.Random` class (see [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Random.html) for details).

**First solution:**

```
Random rand = new Random(438976);   // initialize pseudo-random generator with an arbitrary seed

Point size = screenMetrics();   // so screenMetrics() is called only once
int xSize = size.x; 
int ySize = size.y;

for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    point.x = rand.nextInt(xSize);   // from 0 (inclusive) to xSize (exclusive) 
    point.y = rand.nextInt(ySize);   // from 0 (inclusive) to ySize (exclusive)

    shape = rand.nextInt(3);   // from 0 (inclusive) to 3 (exclusive)


// ...
}
```

**Second solution:**
In order to generate different shapes, you should check if the new generated shape has been previously generated. You could use a `Vector<Integer>` to hold the generated shapes, then you could generate a new shape until it is different from a previously generated shape.

```
Random rand = new Random(438976);   // initialize pseudo-random generator with an arbitrary seed

Point size = screenMetrics();   // so screenMetrics() is called only once
int xSize = size.x; 
int ySize = size.y;

Vector<Integer> generated = new Vector<Integer>(0);    
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    point.x = rand.nextInt(xSize);   // from 0 (inclusive) to xSize (exclusive) 
    point.y = rand.nextInt(ySize);   // from 0 (inclusive) to ySize (exclusive)

    while (true) {
        shape = rand.nextInt(3);   // from 0 (inclusive) to 3 (exclusive)
        if (!generated.Contains(shape)){
            generated.add(shape);
            break;
        }
        else if (generated.size() == 3) {
            generated.clear();
            break;
        }
    }

// ...
}
```

**Third solution:**
You could use different pseudo-random generators and test them with different values of the seed.

```
Random pointsGenerator = new Random();
Random shapeGenerator = new Random(389453294);
Random colorGenerator = new Random(84568);
```

Comment: I've added this, but now no points are drawn.
`Point size = screenMetrics();  
     int xSize = size.x; 
     int ySize = size.y;

     for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
         point.x = rand.nextInt(xSize);   // from 0 (inclusive) to xSize (exclusive) 
         point.y = rand.nextInt(ySize);   // from 0 (inclusive) to ySize (exclusive)

         shape = rand.nextInt(3);   // from 0 (inclusive) to 3 (exclusive)
         
         c = rand.nextInt(3);
      switch(c){
                 //
      }
      points[i] = new scatterPoint(this, point, shape, colour);
     }`

Comment: I posted this comment on the other answer, but it seems that the random number generation is working correctly. Printing out each new point shows good values, however they're not being displayed properly.
Update: nope setting the colour and size constant doesn't change anything, still only one of the 20 shapes are drawn
Sample output:
621, 125 2 1;
549, 286 1 0;
825, 54 2 2;
717, 206 2 2;
39, 400 1 0;
etc.
I'm thinking the change in colour may be killing the draw?

Comment: @battery: I have update my answer. I forgot to specify that the `Vector` should be written before the `for`.
However I added also a detail within the `while`.

Comment: @battery: You may generate the color in the same way of the shape.

Comment: Thing is I don't need every new one to be distinct from the last. I'm fine with repetition.
Also I using your code I get a black screen (infinite loop?) and:
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=scatter.plot/.ScatterPlotActivity }
ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Comment: @battery: I corrected my code. You could also try without using the `generated` vector (the first solution).

Comment: I was essentially running that before trying with the generated vector, but like I said, the generated points are good, but they don't seem to be getting drawn correctly. Any idea where the fault is or what's wrong with my draw method?

Comment: The second argument of `drawCircle` method should be `coordinates.y`. Both the `drawRect` method and the construction of the `Path` seem to be correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help generating the points. I'm still working on the drawing issue but that's a different problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the problem lies in the generation of random numbers.
Have you checked what number *Math.random()* returns, they might not be as random as expected.

Try using the Random number generator, something along the lines, if I remember correctly:

```
 Random generator = new Random(); 
 n = generator.nextInt((int) max);
```

Comment: I created a randomGenerator method to call every time I need a random number that uses your idea, but I still only seem to generate a max of two objects, never a triangle. Also, if two objects are generated, their x coordinate is always the same.

Comment: I used parts of both your answers, it seems that the random number generation is working correctly. Printing out each new point shows good values, however they're not being displayed properly.

Comment: generator.nextInt(max) will return values from 0..(max-1) check if you have considered this.